# Grails - Change value in param map for checkboxes?

Tags: grails

Is there a way that I can change the values put in the param map from checkboxes?  I've noticed that elements with a checkbox will either have a value of "on" in the param map if the checkbox was checked or there will be an underscore preceding the element name as a key in the param map with a value of "" if the checkbox was not checked.  Is there any way I can change this behavior so that a value of "true" will be in the param map if checked and a value of "false" (preferably without the '_' preceding the element's name) if the box was not checked?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**GSP Form**

```
<g:form controller="test" action="testForm">
  <g:checkBox name="box" value="${true}" />
  <g:submitButton name="submit" value="submit" />
</g:form>
```

**Controller Code**

```
def testForm() {
  println params.box as boolean
}
```

**Output**

```
true // when box checked
false // when box unchecked
```

Comment: I'm currently using a domain instance's property as the value. `<g:checkBox name="property" value="${domainInstance.property}" />`  Property is a boolean (of course), so domainInstance.property evaluates to either true or false, yet the params map shows either "property":"on" or "_property":"" depending on if the checkbox is checked.

Comment: Actually, I just noticed that when the checkbox is checked both "property":"on" and "_property":"" are in the params map.  When checkbox is not checked then only "_property":"" is in the params map.

Comment: Take a look through the [source code for the tag on github](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/master/grails-plugin-gsp/src/main/groovy/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/plugins/web/taglib/FormTagLib.groovy) and you will see what's causing the behavior you're seeing and also see what the tag can and can't do.  Keep in mind that unchecked checkboxes are handled in a standard way in HTML (i.e. browsers don't submit a value) so the author of the tag had to work around that constraint.